# Is C# LINQ OrderBy threadsafe when used with ConcurrentDictionary<Tkey, TValue>?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, concurrency, concurrentdictionary

My working assumption is that LINQ is thread-safe when used with the **System.Collections.Concurrent** collections (including **ConcurrentDictionary**).

(Other Overflow posts seem to agree: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27569870/7316540))

However, an inspection of the implementation of the LINQ **OrderBy** extension method shows that it appears not to be threadsafe with the subset of concurrent collections which implement **ICollection** (e.g. **ConcurrentDictionary**).

The **OrderedEnumerable** **GetEnumerator** ([source here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,ffb8de6aefac77cc)) constructs an instance of a **Buffer** struct ([source here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,ed118118b642d9d4)) which tries to cast the collection to an **ICollection** (which **ConcurrentDictionary** implements) and then performs a collection.CopyTo with an array initialised to the size of the collection.

Therefore, if the **ConcurrentDictionary** (as the concrete **ICollection** in this case) grows in size during the OrderBy operation, between initialising the array and copying into it, this operation will throw.

The following test code shows this exception:

(Note: I appreciate that performing an **OrderBy** on a thread-safe collection which is changing underneath you is not that meaningful, but I do not believe it should throw)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Program
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                int loop = 0;
                while (true) //Run many loops until exception thrown
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Loop: {++loop}");

                    _DoConcurrentDictionaryWork().Wait();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }

        private static async Task _DoConcurrentDictionaryWork()
        {
            var concurrentDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, object>();
            var keyGenerator = new Random();
            var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

            var orderByTaskLoop = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var token = tokenSource.Token;
                while (token.IsCancellationRequested == false)
                {
                    //Keep ordering concurrent dictionary on a loop
                    var orderedPairs = concurrentDictionary.OrderBy(x => x.Key).ToArray(); //THROWS EXCEPTION HERE

                    //...do some more work with ordered snapshot...
                }
            });

            var updateDictTaskLoop = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var token = tokenSource.Token;
                while (token.IsCancellationRequested == false)
                {
                    //keep mutating dictionary on a loop
                    var key = keyGenerator.Next(0, 1000);
                    concurrentDictionary[key] = new object();
                }
            });

            //Wait for 1 second
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

            //Cancel and dispose token
            tokenSource.Cancel();
            tokenSource.Dispose();

            //Wait for orderBy and update loops to finish (now token cancelled)
            await Task.WhenAll(orderByTaskLoop, updateDictTaskLoop);
        }
    }
}
```

That the **OrderBy** throws an exception leads to one of a few possible conclusions:

1) My assumption about LINQ being threadsafe with concurrent collections is incorrect, and it is only safe to perform LINQ on collections (be they concurrent or not) which are not mutating during the LINQ query

2) There is a bug with the implementation of LINQ **OrderBy** and it is incorrect for the implementation to try and cast the source collection to an ICollection and try and perform the collection copy (and It should just drop through to its default behaviour iterating the IEnumerable).

3) I have misunderstood what is going on here...

Thoughts much appreciated!

Comment: _"THROWS EXCEPTION HERE"_ What exception?

Comment: Your assumption that the Buffer constructor casting to `ICollection<T>` will succeed was wrong. Because [`ConcurrentDictionary.GetEnumerator`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs,b2dcb93f9ede4ba0,references) was the actual source and this is not a `ICollection<T>`.

Comment: It seems you have answered your own question, not? I mean you see yourself that it's not thread safe to do this.

Comment: There might be a slight difference between ThreadSafe and allowing operations on a collection in an inconsistent state

Comment: I don't get the question IEnumerable methods are not thread safe nor are they intended to be? Where did you find that LINQ is safe with concurrent collections? This is mentioned in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s793z9y2.aspx)

Comment: `Your assumption that the Buffer constructor casting to ICollection<T> will succeed was wrong.` I think @Evk might be right - it does successfully cast to `ICollection<T>`.

Answer (score 9):

It's not stated anywhere that `OrderBy` (or other LINQ methods) should always use `GetEnumerator` of source `IEnumerable` or that it should be thread safe on concurrent collections. All that is promised is this method

> Sorts the elements of a sequence in ascending order according to a
>   key.

`ConcurrentDictionary` is not thread-safe in some global sense either. It's thread-safe with respect to other operations performed on it. Even more, documentation says that

> All public and protected members of ConcurrentDictionary
>   are thread-safe and may be used concurrently from multiple threads.
>   **However**, members accessed through one of the interfaces the
>   ConcurrentDictionary implements, **including extension**
>   **methods**, are not guaranteed to be thread safe and may need to be
>   synchronized by the caller.

So, your understanding is correct (`OrderBy` will see `IEnumerable` you pass to it is really `ICollection`, will then get length of that collection, allocate buffer of that size, then will call `ICollection.CopyTo`, and this is of course not thread safe on any type of collection), but it's not a bug in `OrderBy` because neither `OrderBy` nor `ConcurrentDictionary` ever promised what you assume.

If you want to do `OrderBy` in a thread safe way on `ConcurrentDictionary`, you need to rely on methods that are promised to be thread safe. For example:

```
// note: this is NOT IEnumerable.ToArray()
// but public ToArray() method of ConcurrentDictionary itself
// it is guaranteed to be thread safe with respect to other operations
// on this dictionary
var snapshot = concurrentDictionary.ToArray();
// we are working on snapshot so no one other thread can modify it
// of course at this point real contents of dictionary might not be
// the same as our snapshot
var sorted = snapshot.OrderBy(c => c.Key);
```

If you don't want to allocate additional array (with `ToArray`), you can use `Select(c => c)` and it will work in this case, but then we are again in moot territory and relying on something to be safe to use in situation it was not promised to (`Select` will also not always enumerate your collection. If collection is array or list - it will shortcut and use indexers instead). So you can create extension method like this:

```
public static class Extensions {
    public static IEnumerable<T> ForceEnumerate<T>(this ICollection<T> collection) {
        foreach (var item in collection)
            yield return item;
    }
}
```

And use it like this if you want to be safe and don't want to allocate array:

```
concurrentDictionary.ForceEnumerate().OrderBy(c => c.Key).ToArray();
```

In this case we are forcing enumeration of `ConcurrentDictionary` (which we know is safe from documentation) and then pass that to `OrderBy` knowing that it cannot do any harm with that pure `IEnumerable`. Note that as correctly pointed out in comments by mjwills, this is not exactly the same as `ToArray`, because `ToArray` produces snapshot (locks collection preventing modifications while building array) and `Select` \ `yield` does not acquire any locks (so items might be added\removed right when enumeration is in progress). Though I doubt it  matters when doing things like described in question - in both cases after `OrderBy` is completed - you have no idea whether your ordered results reflect current state of collection or not.

Comment: Could `var snapshot = concurrentDictionary.Select(z => z);` instead be used to avoid the array allocation?

Comment: @mjwills I've updated answer with my thoughts about that.

Comment: Nice work @Evk . Whether to use `ToArray` or `Select` / `yield` depends largely on whether you want a snapshot (i.e. point in time) or not. https://arbel.net/2013/02/03/best-practices-for-using-concurrentdictionary/ `ToArray` will give you snapshot semantics, but the locks involved means it will generally be slightly slower (not to mention the memory cost).

Comment: @mjwills yes you are right, they (Select\yield and ToArray) are not exactly the same. Though if do are doing such things (ordering while adding items at the same time) - I suppose you rarely care if you are working with snapshot or not, because when you are done - source collection might have changed in both cases.

Comment: Very true @Evk.