# Why LINQ method Any does not check Count?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

If we look at source code of extension method `Any` we will se, that it always uses enumerator:

```
public static bool Any<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null)
        throw Error.ArgumentNull(nameof (source));
    using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (enumerator.MoveNext())
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I think, is't it better (for perfomace) to check `Count` property if collection is `IList` like in `SingleOrDefault` method for example:

```
public static TSource SingleOrDefault<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null)
        throw Error.ArgumentNull(nameof(source));
    IList<TSource> sourceList = source as IList<TSource>;
    if (sourceList != null)
    {
        switch (sourceList.Count)
        {
            case 0:
                return default(TSource);
            case 1:
                return sourceList[0];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //...
    }
    throw Error.MoreThanOneElement();
}
```

I say, it can looks like this:

```
private static bool Any<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

    IList<TSource> sourceList = source as IList<TSource>;

    if (sourceList != null)
    {
        return sourceList.Count != 0;
    }

    using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (enumerator.MoveNext())
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I wrote a benchmark to test it:

```
namespace AnyTests
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BenchmarkRunner.Run<Test>();
        }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        private readonly List<int> list1 = new List<int>(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });

        private readonly IEnumerable<int> list2 = GetCollection();

        private static IEnumerable<int> GetCollection()
        {
            yield return 1;
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public void TestLinqAnyList()
        {
            Enumerable.Any(list1);
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public void TestNewAnyList()
        {
            NewAny(list1);
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public void TestLinqAnyEnumerable()
        {
            Enumerable.Any(list2);
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public void TestNewAnyEnumerable()
        {
            NewAny(list2);
        }


        private static bool NewAny<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source)
        {
            if (source == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

            IList<TSource> sourceList = source as IList<TSource>;

            if (sourceList != null)
            {
                return sourceList.Count != 0;
            }

            using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
            {
                if (enumerator.MoveNext())
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Results show that it's about two times better:

```
// * Summary *

BenchmarkDotNet=v0.10.13, OS=Windows 10 Redstone 3 [1709, Fall Creators Update] (10.0.16299.192)
Intel Core i7-7700 CPU 3.60GHz (Kaby Lake), 1 CPU, 8 logical cores and 4 physical cores
Frequency=3515624 Hz, Resolution=284.4445 ns, Timer=TSC
  [Host]     : .NET Framework 4.7.1 (CLR 4.0.30319.42000), 32bit LegacyJIT-v4.7.2600.0
  DefaultJob : .NET Framework 4.7.1 (CLR 4.0.30319.42000), 32bit LegacyJIT-v4.7.2600.0


                Method |     Mean |     Error |    StdDev |
---------------------- |---------:|----------:|----------:|
       TestLinqAnyList | 26.80 ns | 0.1382 ns | 0.1154 ns |
        TestNewAnyList | 12.75 ns | 0.0480 ns | 0.0426 ns |
 TestLinqAnyEnumerable | 18.03 ns | 0.0947 ns | 0.0886 ns |
  TestNewAnyEnumerable | 23.51 ns | 0.0913 ns | 0.0762 ns |
```

For `IList` it's about twice better, for `IEnumerable` it's about 20% worse.

So, the question: what the reason to use optimization in `SingleOrDefault` method and do not use it in `Any` one?

Comment: There is an issue in .net core repository about that: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/23700. You can read first-hand information there about benefits and drawbacks of that (in particular, Jon Hannas' comment). You will find out some surprising things, for example that for arrays - current version is actually faster than checking `ICollection.Count` (while for lists it's a bit slower).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The assumption behind your question is likely:

> Count is fast, why not use it?

One plausible answer of why `Any` doesn't use it is that `Count` is not **always** fast. The advantage of the implementation they chose is that it will have a relatively stable and low cost (i.e. roughly `O(1)`). *It may not be fast as `Count` in all instances however (as you have identified).*

There is no *guarantee* that the class that implements `IList` or `ICollection` will have a **fast** `Count` property. *[`ConcurrentDictionary`](https://ayende.com/blog/179329/public-service-announcement-concurrentdictionary-count-is-locking), for example, is generally slower for `Count > 0` than the existing `Any` implementation.*

*Additionally, your code that uses `IList` should likely use `ICollection` since your code doesn't need the extra features that `IList` provides access to.*

Comment: Spot on. LINQ is built for IEnumerable, not IList. However I would think it would be trivial to support the most common collection classes in the .NET framework.

Comment: In a framework, alas every few things are trivial. :( https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericgu/2004/01/12/minus-100-points/

Comment: But anyway, `SingleOrDefault` uses `Count`. Why, if it can be slow? Just don't understand where it's ok to use "slow" methods, and where not

Comment: Yep, and that means that `SingleOrDefault` would be slow for any type that implements `IList` and has a slow `Count` property @Backs . The nature of LINQ is that it is a slightly leaky abstraction - for each method they are making tradeoffs. Something they get the tradeoffs 'right', sometimes 'wrong' (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47631641/34092). It is hard to build this kind of stuff since the interface (`IList`, `ICollection` or whatever) tells you whether something is **possible**, but not its performance cost. The benefit of existing `Any` is that it has a relatively stable cost.

Comment: @mjwills I've wrote small post about this problem: http://blog.rogatnev.net/2018/06/16/Any-vs-Count.html